# What is the best way to maintain integrity between each database record referring to an file path of an image on a disk?

Tags: database-design

I have a database. One of the contained tables will be used to save the file paths of images on a disk.

The question is

**how to maintain the integrity between each record in the table and the corresponding image file on the disk?**

I want to avoid the possibilities

- a record with unavailable image file.
- an image with no record in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best strategy for maintaining integrity between the two is to eliminate the secondary storage route and store the file bits in the database directly. Most RDBMS have a binary data type that will store straight binary bits.

Have your application serialize/deserialize the bits to reconstitute the file contents as needed. Include a field for filename that includes the extension.

Comment: Saving the images in the database will increase the database file size. It is the constraint that I must obey.

Comment: We took this solution and had lots of issues because of increasing binary data. It becomes difficult and lengthy to backup main data.

Comment: @RecycleBin - yes, the db size will increase. But isn't your requirement to maintain integrity on a file and its metadata in the db?

Comment: @Zimbabao - not sure what issues you're speaking of.  I have managed file bits in this approach multiple times and haven't encountered any issues.

Comment: When data size of these files start dominating. Main problem I got was in backups. They get slow and bulky (Specially when you have million files). So I'll don't store any data in DB which is not available for SQL to act upon.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off handling this in the Application code rather than adding integrity checks in Database.

You would want to add a two-way check: First before the data is uploaded into the database, make sure that the particular file exists. Second when the user retrieves the record throw an exception if the file does not exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, the file can still be removed through the file system -- outside the flow of application code.

Comment: @jro: That's a great point! But hopefully the images are locked atleast when the application code is running.